# Arquillian ContiPerf integration

Tags: jakarta-ee, automated-tests, performance-testing, jboss-arquillian, contiperf

I have successfully developed a toy unit test on ContiPerf 2.
When I try to do the same on an Arquillian unit test, the ContiPerf annotation `@PerfTest` seems not working, while the annotation `@Required` goes fine.
My test class looks like

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class PerformanceFacadeBeanTest {

    @Rule
    public ContiPerfRule i = new ContiPerfRule();

    @EJB
    private PerformanceFacadeRemote performanceRemote;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<EnterpriseArchive> createArchive() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    @InSequence(value=1)
    @PerfTest(invocations = 100, threads = 5)
    @Required(max = 1200, average = 250)
    public void testPerformanceOnCacheLocal() {
    testPerformanceOnCache(performanceLocal);
    }

    private void testPerformanceOnCache(PerformanceFacade performanceFacade) {
    performanceFacade.performOnCache();
    }
}
```

and the exception I get is

```
org.databene.contiperf.PerfTestExecutionError: org.junit.internal.runners.model.MultipleFailureException: There were 2 errors:
  java.lang.NullPointerException(null)
  java.lang.NullPointerException(null)
    at org.databene.contiperf.util.ContiPerfUtil.executionError(ContiPerfUtil.java:66)
    at org.databene.contiperf.junit.JUnitInvoker.invoke(JUnitInvoker.java:54)
    at org.databene.contiperf.util.InvokerProxy.invoke(InvokerProxy.java:46)
    at org.databene.contiperf.PerformanceTracker.invoke(PerformanceTracker.java:97)
    at org.databene.contiperf.CountRunner.run(CountRunner.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any thoughts?
I can post my pom.xml, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you cannot use ContiPerf2 with Arquillian. Currently, Arquillian uses `ThreadLocal` instances for book keeping that are not available to threads spawned by the ContiPerf rule. Hence, the `NullPointerException` since the Arquillian testrunner would fail to locate the ThreadLocal instance in possibly all but one thread. This behavior of Arquillian may change in a future release; no promises in that area though.

I would recommend using [JUnitBenchmarks](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html) for now, since it was reported to work correctly through a custom Arquillian extension.

Comment: it should be possible in 2018 based on https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-ee-8/9781788473064/2466d045-72d1-49db-af31-5d1e64adeef2.xhtml